# Allocate rows to columns from different data frames (lapply operations)

Tags: r

I would like to know how can I allocate a given row of a data frame to a given column of another data frame without merging, aggregating, etc. For example, making row 1 of df1 to be associated with column 1 of df 2, so the operations carried on column 1 of df 2 just take values from row 1 of df 1.

Let´s create df1 (i.e. V) and df2 (i.e. M):

```
V<-data.frame(A=c(2,1),B=c(4,2),C=c(6,3))
M<-data.frame(V1=rep(1,10),V2=rep(2,10)) 

#> V
   A B C
V1 2 4 6
V2 1 2 3

#> M
   V1 V2
1   1  2
2   1  2
3   1  2
4   1  2
5   1  2
6   1  2
7   1  2
8   1  2
9   1  2
10  1  2
```

And let´s create a list of functions to pass on M taking values from V

```
FUNS<-list(
F1<-function(x,A,B,C) A*x+B*x+C*x,
F2<-function(x,A,B,C) A*x-B*x-C*x
)
```

Now I want to pass the list of function on M, (but "ideally" I'd like just to use the values stored in row 1 for column 1 and the ones in row 2 to column 2, and unfortunately I haven´t found how.

```
res1<-list(data.frame(matrix(,10,2)),data.frame(matrix(,10,2)))
for(i in seq_along(V[,1])){
res1[[i]]<-lapply(FUNS,function(f) f(M,V[i,1],V[i,2],V[i,3]))
}
```

This returns:
1) first function implemented on columns one and two with set of values from row 1
2) second function implemented on columns 1 & 2 with set of values from row 1
3) first function implemented on columns 1 & 2 with set of values from row 2
4) second function implemented on columns 1 & 2 with set of values from row 2

What I want is:
1) First and second function implemented on column 1 with just values from row 1
2) First and second function implemented on column 2 with just values from row 2

```
> res1
[[1]]
[[1]][[1]]
   V1 V2
1  12 24
2  12 24
3  12 24
4  12 24
5  12 24
6  12 24
7  12 24
8  12 24
9  12 24
10 12 24

[[1]][[2]]
   V1  V2
1  -8 -16
2  -8 -16
3  -8 -16
4  -8 -16
5  -8 -16
6  -8 -16
7  -8 -16
8  -8 -16
9  -8 -16
10 -8 -16


[[2]]
[[2]][[1]]
   V1 V2
1   6 12
2   6 12
3   6 12
4   6 12
5   6 12
6   6 12
7   6 12
8   6 12
9   6 12
10  6 12

[[2]][[2]]
   V1 V2
1  -4 -8
2  -4 -8
3  -4 -8
4  -4 -8
5  -4 -8
6  -4 -8
7  -4 -8
8  -4 -8
9  -4 -8
10 -4 -8
```

Help is really appreciated!!!
Cheers

Comment: Ollauri I thought the `res1` is the desired output. Instead of posting what you got, could you post the expected output.

Comment: You meant the  `JUST WITH THE FIRST VALUES OF V` as the first row of V, right? That is what I did.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
 resN <- lapply(seq_len(nrow(V)), function(i) {
               v <- unlist(V[i,])
              lapply(seq_along(FUNS), function(i) 
                  FUNS[[i]](M, v[1], v[2], v[3])) })
```

which is the same as `res1`

#### EDIT

From the description, it seems like you want this:

```
  V1 <- as.data.frame(t(V))
  resN1 <- Map(function(.FUN,y,z) do.call(cbind,
               lapply(.FUN, function(x) x(y, z[1],z[2],z[3]))) ,
                                                list(FUNS), M, V1)
   resN1
   #[[1]]
  #     [,1] [,2]
  #[1,]   12   -8
  #[2,]   12   -8
  #[3,]   12   -8
  #[4,]   12   -8
  #[5,]   12   -8
  #[6,]   12   -8
  #[7,]   12   -8
  #[8,]   12   -8
  #[9,]   12   -8
 #[10,]   12   -8

 #[[2]]
 #     [,1] [,2]
 # [1,]   12   -8
 # [2,]   12   -8
 # [3,]   12   -8
 # [4,]   12   -8
 # [5,]   12   -8
 # [6,]   12   -8
 # [7,]   12   -8
 # [8,]   12   -8
 # [9,]   12   -8
 #[10,]   12   -8
```

which is the same as

```
  M[,1]*V[1,1]+M[,1]*V[1,2]+M[,1]*V[1,3]
   #[1] 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12

  M[,1]*V[1,1]-M[,1]*V[1,2]-M[,1]*V[1,3]
   #[1] -8 -8 -8 -8 -8 -8 -8 -8 -8 -8

  M[,2]*V[2,1]+M[,2]*V[2,2]+M[,2]*V[2,3]
   #[1] 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12

  M[,2]*V[2,1]-M[,2]*V[2,2]-M[,2]*V[2,3]
  #[1] -8 -8 -8 -8 -8 -8 -8 -8 -8 -8
```

Comment: Thanks, Akrun. The expected output should be:

Comment: 1)FIRST COLUMN IMPLEMENTED ON FIRST AND SECOND FUNCTION JUST WITH THE FIRST VALUES OF V; 2) SECOND COLUMN IMPLEMENTED ON FIRST AND SECOND FUNCTION JUST WITH THE THE SECOND VALUES OF V

Comment: @A.G.Ollauri  It is exactly how I did that. Also, I showed the reference using calculations

Comment: Amazing!! Thanks so much Akrun. I'm trying to figure out why you include "do.call(cbind)", I guess is for preparing the data for the calculations!!! Apologies for my ignorance.

Comment: @A.G.Ollauri  It is because the columns are in a list.  Please check the result of `Map(function(.FUN, y, z) lapply(.FUN, function(x) x(y, z[1], z[2], z[3])), list(FUNS), M,V1)`  Using `do.call(cbind,.` will bind the columns together.

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you, Akrun. It seems that the family "lapply" is extremely powerful (and a bit tricky to me in the time being). Cheers